# How long are MQTT messages held by broker in QoS 1 or 2?

Tags: rabbitmq, ibm-mq, mq, mqtt

So, if I send a MQTT message with QoS 1 or 2 and one of the receivers to the topic that the message belongs to is offline, how long will the broker keep it in queue and try to keep resending?

Is this a implementation specific detail for the message broker and the MQTT Protocol itself has no rules regarding this?

Comment: This is entirely broker specific. As you appear to be asking a lot of general questions about the protocol, rather than specific technical points suitable for SO, you may want to join the MQTT google group and ask them there in one go. See http://mqtt.org/get-involved for links.

Answer (score 1):

As @knolleary says, this is entirely implementation dependent.

The mosquitto broker provides an option `persistent_client_expiration` for you to control this yourself, but will otherwise keep messages indefinitely up to a maximum quantity as defined by `max_queued_messages`.